# Change button color on mouse hover

Tags: c#

In C #, how to change the color of the buttons when the mouse pointer is on them, so that the color of the button returns to the previous color when the mouse leaves it.

Comment: the mousehover event? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: More likely `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events?

Answer (score 11):

Supposing you are using Windows.Forms you can add event handlers to the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events of your `Button` and set the `Button`'s `BackColor` property accordingly:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    button1.MouseEnter += OnMouseEnterButton1;
    button1.MouseLeave += OnMouseLeaveButton1;
  }

  private void OnMouseEnterButton1(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    button1.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonHighlight; // or Color.Red or whatever you want
  }
  private void OnMouseLeaveButton1(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    button1.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonFace;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No need hover/leave events or drawing.

Just make your button flat and use [MouseOverBackColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flatbuttonappearance.mouseoverbackcolor) property.

```cs
Button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
Button.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Red; //color you want it to be background on hover
```

Answer (score 3):

below code worked for me.

```
private void shipdbutton_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    shipdbutton.BackColor = Color.White;
}

private void shipdbutton_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    shipdbutton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(32, 38, 71); // ****add the color you want here.**
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not really being very specific, but you could use the MonoGame library if you wanted to. If you do choose to use it (generally not recommended for simple programs like a calculator, but it does the job nonetheless), you should do something like this:

```
//1. Declare your button's texture, and some other stuff (button rectangle, etc.).    
Texture2D My_texture;
Rectangle buttonBox;
bool isMouseIn = false;

//2. Load your button's texture in the LoadContent() method.
My_texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("name of your resource");

//3. Handle the input in the Update() method.
MouseState currentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();
if(buttonBox.Contains(currentMouseState.Position))
{
    isMouseIn = true;
}


//4. Draw the button in the Draw() method.
spriteBatch.Begin();
if(isMousein)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(My_texture, buttonBox, Color.Red;
}
else
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(My_texture, buttonBox, Color.Blue);
}
spriteBatch.End();
```

It is however better to use Windows Forms as the other answer says, since it is more suited to such a simple program and does not require a very polished or flexible graphical interface.