# How to change border colour of buttons when hovered over (c# | Visual Studio)

Tags: c#

How can I change the colour of the borders of my button when a mouse hovers over it. So one i hover over the button the border changes colour from yellow to pink and when i stop hovering it goes back to yellow.

I want to change the colour of the border not the actual button

Comment: Is C# only the requirement?

Comment: While you know what kind of button you're asking about, nobody else does. Consider how other people with no knowledge about what you're doing would read your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change button color on mouse hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34024612/change-button-color-on-mouse-hover)

Comment: c# only @Scath As that is what ive used to create my program

Comment: need people with knowledge obviously. Thats why im asking @Will

Comment: Winforms? WPF? Html? ...

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow That is changing the button colour not the border which is what im asking.

Comment: @TerryTyson Visual Studio using C#

Comment: "need change button c#" "what kind of button?" "button, c#." Muh mind, it boggle.

Answer (score 0):

if you work it in windows forms, no one button have this style changer,and then I don't know how to fix it.
but if u work in wpf u must try to write our own template like this

```
<Button Content="Button">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button" >
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Control.IsFocused" Value="True"> 
                        <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="Pink" />                        
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Olive" /> 
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="True"> 
                        <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="LightYellow" /> 
                        <Setter Property="Control.FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Olive" /> 
                    </Trigger> 
                    <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True"> 
                        <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="Red" /> 
                    </Trigger> 

                </Style.Triggers>   
            </Style>    
        </Button.Style> 
    </Button>
```